# Physics.Raycast always fails when embedded with -parentHWND

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, embed

I have embedded a Unity application into a parent WPF application. However, this has had some odd side effects.

I have an update method that constantly checks if the mouse 0 button is pressed and, if so, does a Raycast to try and find that object. This is shown here:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        //Some code here...
    }
}
```

This raycast always fails. However, when done inside of the unity editor (I.E., pressing play when in the engine), it works fine.

Another weird behavior is that, if using the standalone player, none of the controls work. I have a different method to rotate a camera around an object:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        float h = rotateSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float v = rotateSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        if (cameraOrbit.transform.eulerAngles.z + v <= 0.1f || cameraOrbit.transform.eulerAngles.z + v >= 179.9f)
            v = 0;

        cameraOrbit.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(cameraOrbit.transform.eulerAngles.x, cameraOrbit.transform.eulerAngles.y + h, cameraOrbit.transform.eulerAngles.z);
    }
```

Which works fine both in the editor and when embedded, but not when using the Unity player. Is there something i'm doing wrong here that's causing this undesired and inconsistent behavior?

Comment: This is probably some kind of compatibility issue. Because it is likely not a code problem. The best you can do is set up some debug.log points and catch any exceptions, to try to see where/why it is failing. Hopefully you will get some very clear exceptions, like target framework xyx error.

Comment: @TylerS.Loeper I did some more digging, and it seems like the actual raycast is working, but it is not going to the correct place, but only when it's embedded. The rays are correct in the Unity editor, but not in the compiled version.

Comment: In the embedded one you might get incorrect `Input.MousePosition`? Did you try to debug that?

Comment: @derHugo Been trying all day. I'm now drawing visible lines using LineRenderer to show me where the rays are hitting, and they're all off by a wide margin. But i've yet to figure out why, and more importantly, why it's only happening when embedded

Comment: @derHugo Do you know what might be causing an incorrect Input.MousePosition output?